# ScalaJs: How to define ScrollView with contentContainerStyle

Tags: scala, react-native, scala.js, scalajs-react

In ScalaJs, I want to use justifyContent and alignItems style attribute but when I do it through normal style it says:

ScrollView child layout (["alignItems", "justifyContent"]) must be applied through the contentContainerStyle prop.

```
def render() = {

    ScrollView(style = UniversalStyleSheet.style(attribute = "value"))(
        .
        .
        .
    )
  }
```

Please share some code if possible

Answer (score 1):

You can simply pass `contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}` to the `ScrollView`.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview.html#contentcontainerstyle

Comment: I appreciate your answer Owen but I need this in ScalaJs

Comment: I'm not familiar with scala but could you not pass the `contentContainerStyle` prop in the `ScrollView` method instead of `style`?